# Error uploading images directory using OpenCV in python using Google Colab

Tags: file-upload

I am trying to upload images directory in python using OpenCV. I am using following code:

```
Image_Directory = ('/content/drive/My Drive/DLAI/CN/Week2/images_1')
path = os.path.join(Image_Directory, '*g')
Directory_Files = glob.glob(path)
Data = []
for file in Directory_Files:
  img = cv2.imread(file)
  Data.append(img)

Directory_List = next(os.walk(Image_Directory))[2]
Directory_List
```

the syntax is returning with error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ce1943f93bce> in <cell line: 8>()
      6   Data.append(img)
      7 
----> 8 Directory_List = next(os.walk(Image_Directory))[2]
      9 Directory_List
```

I am expecting a python list with names of images files in the directory

Comment: The problem you're encountering has nothing to do with OpenCV, so I removed the misused tag. Really, it has nothing to do with file uploading either. (Honestly that `imread` doesn't make much sense -- you want to upload the raw, uncompressed pixel data? Why?)